# Javascript how to disable long click on table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I im using datatables that have in last row 4 buttons...when i click on second button i need to get normal click() event and when i press long click (say 1sec) i need to fire long click() event...that works fine using this code but when i start for example clicking on table it fires long click() events so how can i enable click() and long click() evenet only on button:

```
<button type="button" id="row-restart" class="btn btn-success row-restart" title="Restart"><i class="fa fa-cogs-refresh fa-2x"></i></button>
```

That is added in:

```
table#basicDataTable -> tbody -> tr#15 -> td -> button#row-restart
```

/* RESTART - server row long click */
        var pressTimer;

```
    $('#basicDataTable').on('mouseup', 'button#row-restart', function(e) {
        /* DEFAULT - disable event */
        e.preventDefault();
        /* CLEAR - timeout */
        clearTimeout(pressTimer);
        return false;
    }).mousedown(function(e){
        /* DEFAULT - disable event */
        e.preventDefault();
        window.type = 1;
        /* SET - timeout */
        pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() { window.type = 2; $('#basicDataTable button#row-restart').click(); }, 1000);
        return false; 
    });
```

And here is click() events that works fine:

```
 $('#basicDataTable').on('click', 'button.btn.btn-ban.ban.row-test', function(e) {
        var message;
        /* DEFAULT - disable event */
        e.preventDefault();

        /* my custom code */
});
```

So i need click and longclick on button after 1sec but it must not fire click and longclick when clicking on table elements.

I im trying to figure out 2days but i can't find where i make mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by finding code here on forum and now it does not fire on table elements only on buttons in table...like it should do:

```
    //from e-OS menu script
var longpress = 1000;
var start;
var timer;

//short press - show e-OS system menu
//long press - show e-OS settings
$('#basicDataTable').on( 'mousedown', 'button#row-restart', function(e) {
    window.type = 1;
    start = new Date().getTime();
    timer = setTimeout(function(){ window.type = 2; $('#basicDataTable button#row-restart').click(); },1000)
}).on( 'mouseleave', function( e ) {
    start = 0;
    clearTimeout(timer);
}).on( 'mouseup', function( e ) {
    if ( new Date().getTime() < ( start + longpress )  ) {
       clearTimeout(timer);
       console.log('short press!');   
    }
});
```